# How do trigger the key combination 'CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER' using Testcafe .keypress()?

Tags: keyboard, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I am trying to run an e2e test with TestCafe and the scenario is that when user press the keys 'CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER' it should trigger an event. it works when i use the keyboard but not within the E2E. Thank you for your help.

the command i use is :

```js
t.keypres('ctrl+shift+enter');
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you are using seems incorrect. Try

```
await t.pressKey('ctrl+shift enter');
```

Refer https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/press-key.html

Comment: Code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Comment: @RyanNerd Thank you for the feedback. I have added a link to refer the explanation

Comment: @RyanNerd thank you for your reply. I tried all this combinations without success

'ctrl+shift+enter'
'ctrl+shift enter'
'ctrl shift enter'